# Security Error on blog: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at

Tags: wordpress, security, web, cors

Why the following security error would rise on a wordpress blog?:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/gentiumbasic/v7/KCktj43blvLkhOTolFn-MZ_RtrTXGeaL_Dia6_H9gNs.woff.
>   This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or
>   enabling CORS.

A search for this show me some other blog sites have the same "error", but i don't understand why is this, i dont know what is CORS, and im not trying to use that.

So i should suppose this is coming from wordpress itself or some installed plugin?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using wordpress then check for the link in setting(admin)

Add WWW in WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem , And i believe the theme you are using have added some font from gstitic.com and that file need to allow your site by giving access of that file that is "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.example.com" where http://www.example.com is your site.

If you download some premium theme for free that could be happen, so please buy that theme before using, If you already bought that one then please contact to it's developer.